# I have access to companies internal files through SSRF and Path traversal both but want to leverage it further to website takeover

Tags: php, apache, websites, unix

I have access to companies internal files through SSRF and Path traversal both but want to leverage it further to website takeover. Thus I can increase the impact and get more bounty then what they will pay now.

I have access to files like

```
/etc/passwd
/etc/hosts etc
```

similarly for SSRF - 127.0.0.1:22 , 127.0.0.1:25

this are the endpoints which I though might be sensitive and can give me info to takeover website.

is there anything more I should look for?

And they don't have any upload file or system where I can upload my .php shell, so its been days I am just stuck here:(

Comment: How do you trigger the SSRF and file reads?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just takeover of the *site*, not necessarily the actual *server*, you have one obvious option: steal the TLS private key (it'll be somewhere the server can read; there's ways to avoid that but they imply much more attention to security than these vulns imply) and then attack the users. You can either MitM users connecting to the real site, or use DNS spoofing to simply impersonate the legitimate server (though probably only for people on the local network).

Other things you might look for:

- Any kind of credential file or string, such as for DNS, or database connections, or similar. Even if those don't give you direct control over the server, they might give you access (potentially even code execution) to other components.
- SSH private keys (you'd need root for this one). Probably not useful unless you can MitM the people who maintain the site, but maybe. If you can find any SSH *client* private keys, you can use them to log into any system that trusts the corresponding public key, though you might have to defeat any private key encryption password first.
- Any metadata or control/coordination/deployment servers. If your SSRF vector is good enough and their security weak enough, you might be able to command or at least access other nodes in the cluster.
- JWT signing key. This would allow you to mint trusted tokens for arbitrary users.